# Java Hibernate Error while execution

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to execute a hibernate Java program but I am getting the error in the pic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

U need to add dependency for h2 database. If added, u should also add it in deployment assembly if deploying on server

Comment: can you tell me how by steps. Thanks